# About jounce (snap)

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, jerk

[About jounce (snap)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth,_fifth,_and_sixth_derivatives_of_position). So change in acceleration is know as jerk, so like this is still imaginable but what is change in jerk, like can you give some real life example where that is happening.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth,_fifth,_and_sixth_derivatives_of_position#:~:text=Snap%2C%20or%20jounce%2C%20is%20the,jerk%20with%20respect%20to%20time. Take a look at this. There is a real life example of snap in that

Comment: A boring simple harmonic oscillator has jerk, snap, crackle, pop, and an infinite number of *other* still higher derivatives of position. There’s nothing interesting about them except their silly names.

Comment: @Ghoster higher order derivatives might not be particularly interesting, but jerk does come up in the [Abraham-Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force).

Comment: Okay got it ! Thankss